# Issue with updating field in a table using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to update one field of my table tblusers the first time a user logs in. So the code am using is the following:

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim MySQL As String
Set db= CurrentDb

If IsNull(firstlogindate) = True  Then
    MySQL = "update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where empid = " & txtempid & ""
    db.Execute MySQL, dbfailOnError
End If
```

But then nothing happens. However when I try the code using: 
`If IsNull(firstlogindate) = True or  firstlogindate = ""` Then
It works but then it updates the field to the current date anytime. Meaning the firstlogin date gets updated to the current date anytime.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do use in your code modules:

```
Option Explicit
```

I guess you are thinking of this:

```
MySQL = "update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where empid = " & txtempid & " and firstlogindate is null"
db.Execute MySQL, dbfailOnError
```

Comment: No I don't use Option explicit. I rather use Option Compare Binary. I also tried MySQL = "update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where empid = " & txtempid & " and firstlogindate is null"
db.Execute MySQL, dbfailOnError but nothing.

Comment: Then firstlogindate is Null or txtempid is not found.

Comment: Option Explicit specifies not to allow variables to be used unless they have been declared. Saves you all kinds of troubles with typos. Option Compare is a second Option statement. It's usual to include both.

Comment: Thx a lot Gustav. And many thanks to Ben for the precision given. I will try to figure out a way to handle it.